# How to Run a PHP Script for every half an hour with out cronjob

Tags: php

How to run a Run a PHP Script for every half an hour with out **cronjob** ?

Comment: With a web service cronjob, or a cronjob on your personal computer invoking the URL. In any case: with a cronjob.

Comment: in addition to @mario http://www.easycron.com/

Comment: @mario hey , my question is that i want to run a script in my local host for every half an hour . i gooogle it but all result came as i have to use cronjob. without it how to do it

Comment: In Windows, create a new Task in Task Scheduler, and enter this as the command: path/to/php/php-cgi.exe -q path/to/php/file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it checking last update date for a file (that acts as flag).

index.php (or any file)

```
<?php
$stat = stat("flag.txt");
if(check if your $stat['mtime'] has more of 30 mins of last modification) {
 //run your script
 touch("flag.txt")
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than PHP code, this could be achieved by a messaging queue systems which is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sleep` method in php script

like this

```
while(1)
{
//what do you want write here 
sleep(30*60)
}
```

because sleep method of php is work in seconds check this link [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

You can run your code in terminal,this is the alternate of unix cron

```
php filename.php
```